# How to inject content script inside an html page which runs within an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome extension which contains two html pages the `background.html` and `helper.html`.

I am trying to inject code into the `helper.html` which runs of course inside the  extension. `helper.html` runs as a `popup` window which I created with chrome.`windows.create(object createData, function callback)`.  However, so far I am unable to do so. From the documentation I understand that my Content Script rule should be

```
   "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["chrome-extension://*/*"],
          "js": ["jquery.js","myscript.js"],
           "css": ["style.css"],
          "run_at": "document_end"
        }
```

but it fails.

Note that when I use localhost instead, for example

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost/"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","myscript.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
```

it works. The localhost runs the exact same code but somehow the extension refuses to recognize the file I am trying to match ( `"matches": ["chrome-extension://*/*"]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome extensions can't inject content scripts into Chrome extensions.

You'll want to use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) instead.